# Change styles on ngb-tab title

Tags: angular, bootstrap-4, ng-bootstrap

I would like to style the title in ngb-tab so that it is not the default blue of an anchor tag. Ideally something like this, but the class property doesn't seem to have an effect on ngb-tab.

The HTML:

```
<ngb-tabset #t="ngbTabset">
    <ngb-tab [title]="'Followers'" class="tab-title">
        <ng-template ngbTabContent>
            ...
        </ng-template>
    </ngb-tab>
    <ngb-tab [title]="'Following'" class="tab-title">
        <ng-template ngbTabContent>
            ...
        </ng-template>
    </ngb-tab>
</ngb-tabset>
```

The CSS:

```
.tab-title {
  color: inherit;
}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

According to the documentation https://ng-bootstrap.github.io/#/components/tabs/ you can style the title by using their `ngbTabTitle` directive.

Example:

```
<ngb-tabset>
 <ngb-tab>
  <ng-template ngbTabTitle><span class="tab-title">Fancy Title</span></ng-template>
  <ng-template ngbTabContent>Content</ng-template>
 </ngb-tab>    
</ngb-tabset>
```

Answer (score 3):

The better option it's the Everest's answer. But as another answer you can use in your component encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.None

```
@Component({
  ...
  templateUrl: 'my-component.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./my-component.component.css'],
  encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.None
})
```

This make the css are written to the document head. So, this css apply to entire application. If you want not, you can enclosed the navtab in a div

```
<div class="customTab">
 <ngb-tabset>
  <ngb-tab title="Simple" class="myClass">
    <ng-template ngbTabContent>
      ...
 <ngb-tabset>
</div>
```

And your .css like

```
.customTab .nav-tabs .nav-link.active
{
    color:black;
}
.customTab .nav-tabs .nav-link
{
    color:cyan;
}
```

for more information about ViewEncapsulation see, e.g. https://blog.thoughtram.io/angular/2015/06/29/shadow-dom-strategies-in-angular2.html

Answer (score 1):

I was trying to change the background color of the inactive tab (the difference between active and inactive tabs was too subtle) and was able to do it via styling in global styles.scss:

```
ngb-tabset ul.nav-tabs li a.nav-link.active {
  background-color: transparent;
}

ngb-tabset ul.nav-tabs li a.nav-link {
  background-color: #eeeeee;
}
```